# Update and reload component in react native

Tags: react-native, synchronization, reload, page-refresh

I am trying to refresh/ reload the page with an updated document once I click on a button. saveAnnotations(); saves the changes made to the document on the device and also updates the document with any other updates from other devices in the database.
The filepath is a REST URL to get the document.
After I click the sync button, the edits made to the document are saved but I want to reload the page so that it pulls the latest updated document from the database in the onclick button itself.

When I go back and return on this page I am able to see the lastest changes made but I want the document to reload when I click on sync button.

I tried using window.location.reload(false); but it closes the page where as I just want to reload the page or rerender filepath props to pull latest changes when I click on the sync button.

Any suggestions on how do I achieve that?

here's my code snippet

```js
reRender = () => {
        // calling the forceUpdate() method
        this.forceUpdate();
        window.location.reload(false);
      };
render() {
return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <DocumentView
                    document={filepath}
                />
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Button
                        onPress={() => {
                            // Save Document
                            this.saveAnnotations();
                        }}
                        title="Sync"
                    />
                </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you are looking for, you need to trigger the `render` method. Doing this will show the updated document. [Here](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) is a diagram showing the lifecycle methods of React components. As you can see, there are three ways to trigger the `render` method:

1. The component receives new props
2. Calling `setState`
3. Calling `forceUpdate`

For your use case, I would suggest adding a call to `forceUpdate`, like so:

```
<View style={styles.button}>
    <Button
        onPress={() => {
            // Save Document
            this.saveAnnotations();
            this.forceUpdate(); // <-- add this
        }}
        title="Sync"
     />
</View>
```